# Display Images in gridview (Multiple Images)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have implemented a functionality where the Images path gets stored in the database and the Images are stored in the server.

Now, what i want is whenever the images has been uploaded, the path should gets saved in the table and from there I want the images to be shown in the gridview.

I have made a gridview for displaying the Images, currently it is taking the `Image_path` in that column i want to display `Images` instead of path.

Also, Please see the code of Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdGalleryData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1"
              Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2" CssClass="hoverTable" DataKeyNames="Id">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="gallery_id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="image_title" HeaderText="Gallery title" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="image_description" HeaderText="Gallery Description" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="image_path" HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind for inserting the images into the table:-

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile == false)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('Please select the file.')</script>", false);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename));

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_gallery_stack(gallery_id, image_title, image_description, image_path) values (@gallery_id,@image_title,@image_description,@image_path)", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gallery_id", ddlImagesId.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_title", txtImageTitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_description", txtImageDescription.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_path", filename);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to display Images in the gridview here.

Comment: use image control in template field instead of bound field.

Comment: Use asp:imagefield refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

Comment: @صفي: let me try that..!!

Comment: @SainPradeep: `asp:imagefield ` it is giving not a known element

Comment: i think you are not writing in the proper case. this is the tag  <asp:ImageField ></asp:ImageField>. Please follow the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="image_path" HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
```

To this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("image_path") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Update from Nadeem.**

In the ASPX file:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Width="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgDisplay" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Getimage(Eval("image_path").ToString()) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected string Getimage(string img)
{
    if (img != "")
        return ("~/GalleryImages/" + img);
    else
        return ("Images/noimg.gif");
}
```

Comment: why it is like that, on every load i am not able to view the gridview ?

Comment: Now the image is not coming, i mean the path issue

Comment: @NadeemKhan Do you see a broken image? Try to right-click it -> Properties and see what's the path.

Comment: the full path is `D:\Ongoing\CSRProject\CSRProject\CSRProject\GalleryImages\IMG_9865_bkp.jpg` but in DB it is just taking the image name

Comment: You can'reference that path, it must be inside your web project.

Comment: so what should I do to make image viewable ?

Comment: @NadeemKhan that path is what's inside the database?

Comment: @NadeemKhan what you gave?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68224/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-king-code).